# Как задать цвет для QGis в Json?

Tags: c#, json, geojson, qgis

Есть список объектов Spot, у которых есть свойства Coordinates и bool IsInsolated. Я эти объекты сериализую в json, а именно в GeoJson, и изображаю в QGis.Как мне на основе свойства IsInsilated указывать цвет отображения точки? Хочу чтобы при true была зеленая, а при false была красная. Как мне внести информацию о цвете в Json и отобразить именно в QGis? Или если он этого не поддерживает, что тогда использовать чтобы все работало?